# How to create a file that will start 3 different instances of iTerm (or 3 different windows in iTerm) and run a command in each one of them?

Tags: script, iterm, automation

Every time I restart my mac I have to open a bunch of iTerm windows/split panes and in each one of them run some commands to start my project. How can I do that in macOS?

Comment: You can do it using **AppleScript** (or **Python**) as **iTerm** is scriptable. Have a look at: [https://iterm2.com/documentation.html](https://iterm2.com/documentation.html)